# Second Moment of an Increasing Term Annuity

Tags: probability, statistics, actuarial-science

I have an arithmetically increasing term annuity-due payable to a life aged $x$ for at most $n$ years under which the payment at time $t$ is $t+1$ for $t=0,1,\dots,n-1$.  The actuarial present value is
$$
\require{enclose} (I\ddot{a})_{x:\enclose{actuarial}{n}}= \sum_{t=0}^{n-1}(t+1)v^t \hspace0.1cm _tp_x \hspace0.2cm ,
$$
where $v=(1+i)^{-1}$, $i$ is the interest rate, and $_tp_x$ is the probability that a life aged $x$ survives at least $t$ years.  I cannot seem to derive the second moment from this definition.  My guess was
$$
\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}(t+1)^2v^{2t} \hspace0.1cm _tp_x \hspace0.2cm.
$$
However, when I evaluate this for specific $x$ and $n$ values, the second moment is too small for the variance to be positive.
Could someone please help me figure out is wrong with my formula?

Comment: That notation won't make sense to $99.99\%$ of the users of this site.  I understand that it is standard actuarial notation.  I suggest editing the question to use more standard notation or, at least, define the notation you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @lulu.  I know that the notation is very specialized, but I am looking for help from someone who would understand it.  Would I be better off posting to a different Stack Exchange site?

Comment: Don't know.  Actuarial notation is *very* specialized.  At one point, I knew how to read it, but I am extremely rusty.  I really suggest writing it out in standard notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\require{enclose}$The present value random variable is $$Y = \begin{cases} (I\ddot a)_{\enclose{actuarial}{K+1}}, & 0 \le K < n, \\ (I \ddot a)_{\enclose{actuarial}{n}}, & K \ge n \end{cases}$$ where $K$ is the curtate lifetime random variable.

Consequently the actuarial present value of the annuity may then be expressed as
$$(I\ddot a)_{x:\enclose{actuarial}{n}} = \operatorname{E}\left[Y\right] = \sum_{t=0}^{n-1} (I \ddot a)_{\enclose{actuarial}{t+1}} \; {}_t p_x \; q_{x+t} + (I\ddot a)_{\enclose{actuarial}{n}} \; {}_n p_x. \tag{1}$$  Note that this formula differs from yours in that we have expressed it in terms of the total present value payment conditional upon death in the interval $[t, t+1)$.  This allows us to write the second moment as

$$\operatorname{E}[Y^2] = \sum_{t=0}^{n-1} \left((I\ddot a)_{\enclose{actuarial}{t+1}}\right)^2 \; {}_t p_x \; q_{x+t} + \left((I\ddot a)_{\enclose{actuarial}{n}}\right)^2 \; {}_n p_x. \tag{2}$$

Whether such an expression can be simplified further (I suspect it can but have not tried), I leave to you as an exercise.  One idea is to set up a table of present values of payments at times $t = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$ for each outcome of $K \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots \}$, and then look at the square of the sums to see if you can simplify.